# How to access data from API Payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server

I am making an api call like this
axios.get("http://localhost:4000/loginUser", { email: enteredEmail, password: enteredPass})
now i want in the server code to access these email and password fields given to the API call,

```
app.get("/loginUser", async (req, res) => {
   try {
        email = // don't know how to access this email field from **req**
   } catch (error) {
         res.status(400).send("invalid credentials");
   }
});
```

i tried accesssing it from res.body but it is empty as i am passing the data as payload. and tried passing as params but the @ symbol in email is giving issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config):

> ```
> axios.get(url[, config])
> ```

The second argument to `get` is the **configuration** not the request body.

GET requests can't have bodies.

If you want to encode data in a GET request, you can do it in the URL (**do not do this for passwords**).

```
const url = new URL("http://localhost:4000/loginUser");
url.searchParams.set("email", enteredEmail);
url.searchParams.set("password", enteredPass);
axios.get(url);
```

where it will be accessible in Express via [the `query` property](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

---

If you want to pass credentials **do not use the URL**. Requested URLs tend to be logged in clear text by web servers.

Make a POST request instead.